# How to get summery from saved search using suite talk api netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

I have created saved search on Netsuite and trying to get summary for saved search using suite talk API.

I am able to get records for saved search using API but not summary result.
Is there any way to get the summary result .
[Saved Search image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAP9n.png)

Thanks,

Hitesh Kumar

Answer (score 2):

Currently NetSuite does not support Summary Saved Searches using their APIs.

If you attempt to complete a saved search that is a summary you get an error, “We cannot return search columns for summary saved search ”

The following is from their Suite Talk Web Services Platform Guide.

[image]

If anyone were to come up with a work around for this I would love to hear what you have.

Comment: hi I just need Rest Api savesearch URL to get savedsearch results, I am tired to find savedsearch URL for suit talk rest API but I can not find the keyword to use in restapi. If you know the rest API suittalk for savedsearch please let me know I Would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using suite analytics and the ODBC driver for our search and it ended up matching.